# one page scroll issues on mobile using Foundation

Tags: html, css, scroll, zurb-foundation

I am having a hard time understanding why when I resize the browser to thin as possible on my comp my one page scrolling sections doesn't scroll to the correct part of the page.

For example, when browser is minimized to as thin as possible when I click the navigation at the top (lets say 'about') when the link is clicked the page scrolls down to the correct section of the code but not at the top of the section.

[Github link to source code](https://github.com/rossmiester/Foundation_portfolio)

If you go to folder yeoman>app>css>app_override.css you will be able to view my overridden css code.

If you go to folder yeoman>app>index.html you will see my index.html file.

FYI I updated the height css for each section to height: 100vh; //viewport height

////////////////////// CSS //////////////////////////

```
section#home {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

section#about {
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

section#contact {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}


section#web-design {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;  
}

section#apps {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  top: -45px;
}

.top-bar {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.top-bar-section {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

///////////////////////////// HTML /////////////////////////

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation project</title>
    <!-- build:css css/libraries.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css css/app.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app_override.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js js/vendor/modernizr.min.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contain-to-grid fixed">
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="sticky_on: [small,medium,large]">
        <ul class="title-area">
          <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#home">mikeTheDev</a></h1>
          </li>
         <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
          <!-- Right Nav Section -->
          <ul class="right">
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#works">Works</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#web-design">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#apps">Apps</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        </section>
      </nav>
     </div>

    <section id="home" class="section">

    </section>

    <section id="web-design" class="section">

    </section>

    <section id="apps" class="section">

    </section>

    <section id="about" class="section">

    </section>

    <section id="contact" class="section">

    </section>

    <!-- <div class="panel">
      <h5>This is a regular panel.</h5>
      <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
    </div> -->

        <!-- build:js js/vendor/libraries.min.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->
        <!-- build:js js/vendor/foundation.min.js -->
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.accordion.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.alert.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.interchange.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.slider.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.tab.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
        <!-- build:js js/app.min.js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
</html>


/////////////////////////////// JS ////////////////////////

// creates a smooth scroll animation when the top bar nav anchor is clicked - scrolls down to link section on page

    $(".top-bar li a").click(function() {
        // stores the href attribute that is clicked in variable called page
        var page_location = $(this).attr('href'); 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(page_location).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should probably include all relevant code within the question rather than a link to your github.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my post above.

Comment: Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: k maybe I should take this down